# Battery consideration and topology choice

Tags: batteries, buck, boost

I have a system with a battery. I do not know what will be the battery at the moment. And so I can select the voltage battery in function of my system. I need to regulate a voltage (15 V) thanks to a converter. The output current will be around 10 A, i.e 150 W.

The question is it better to use a boost converter or a buck converter for doing the job as I can choose the voltage level of the battery? Also I think that If the voltage level of the battery increase, it will also increase the output impedance of the battery as more cell will be put in series and so when some current will be drawn by the load, the voltage of the battery will be lower. Also I think that the battery will have a lower energy density if I increase the voltage than if I took a battery with a lower voltage. So I think that it will be better to use a boost converter. But as I do not know really much battery, I would appreciate to have your opinions.

I put away the non inverting buck boost topologies as it would be less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple thing to be answered in a few sentences. Different things should be considered together such as failure modes, environmental conditions, cost, etc. I'll try to cover only a limited section of these.

Whether you go for a buck or a boost, the complexity, overall efficiency, and material cost will be pretty much the same for both.

Lower battery voltage and boost converter require thicker input wires, but higher battery voltage and buck converter require good interconnection of the batteries/cells. This will make you consider the overall build of the system. And, for now, we can assume the power loss at input section to be equal for both buck and boost.

Practically speaking, 10 Amps is not a low number for an output current. It's high enough to give you headache due to the losses and heat.

If you go for a boost converter with, say, 12V battery voltage, the rectifier diode will be in conduction for almost 80% of a switching cycle (assuming CCM). This means that the diode dissipation will be substantial. You can go for a synchronous boost converter and replace the rectifier with a MOSFET but it's not a common thing these days. So you can select a higher battery voltage and go for a synchronous buck instead.

You should also consider the potential failures:

- In a boost converter if the switch fails first it'll short the battery. But if the rectifier diode fails first your load will see the input voltage, 12V.
- In a sync buck converter, if the top switch fails first the load will see the full input voltage, presumably 24V. But if the bottom switch fails first the battery will be shorted.

There are also other possible failure modes. If you want to deep dive into the details google "FMEA".

- Consider the potential danger of the load being exposed to higher or lower voltage.
- Do a rough calculation/estimation of the losses and cooling of the critical components, and take the complexity and implementation difficulties along with cost and availability, and decide which is acceptable for you. Since there's no such thing as "best" in engineering, it is not to make the best but it's to make the "good enough".

PS: Personally, I'd start with a synchronous buck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all the details you have mentionned :) ! Do you know why synchronous boost converter are less common than synchronous buck converter ?

Comment: @Jess to be honest I don't know. I have just checked the availability over Digikey and actually there are quite a few. Might be worth considering.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to get more information about it to understand why there is less synchronous boost converter than buck converter.